# Problem with xymatrix figure__> error: unknown float option

Tags: floats, compilation-error, undefined, xymatrix

I have this code (xy and float packages loaded, (do I really need float?)), editor: texmaker:

```
\begin{figure}[h,scale=0.9] \tightdisplaymath
 \[ 
 \xymatrix{ *+[F]{\text{Adina (x)}}  \ar@/^2pc/[r]^{r_{xz}>0\ (x\uparrow,z\uparrow)} \ar@/_2pc/[rr]_{r_{xy}<0\ (x\uparrow,y\downarrow)}
 & *+[F]{\text{Absentismoa(z)}}  \ar@/^2pc/[r]^{r_{zy}<0\ (z\uparrow,y\downarrow)}  
 & *+[F]{\text{Ekoizpena(y)}}\\
  }
  \]
\caption{Absentismoa}
\end{figure}
```

This gives me these multiple errors: unknown float option '0','.', '9' ,'=' ,'a' ,'s' ...., and also undefined control sequence, all in the first line code (begin{figure}...). Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error is fairly clear I think, `[h,scale=0.9]` is not a valid option to `figure`you could use `[htp]`or even just `[h]`   similarly `\tightdisplaymath` is not a command I recognise. If you have seen this defined in some example, that example presumably showed you a definition.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!